# Explicit songs won't play on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, music, music.app

Songs marked explicit won't play on my iPhone.

Was working well last week then suddenly stopped. I press the song and it looks as if it's playing but it is silent. Move to the next non-explicit song and plays well.

I have explicit on my restrictions and set to the US. Also my Music app freezes when trying to play the songs.

iPhone 7 Plus, iOS 12.3.1

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  When you say it's `set to the US`, what exactly is set?  Can you [edit] your question to include a screenshot?  This is mostly due to your location as some countries prohibit this regardless of your setting.

Comment: Hey! [Apple parental controls](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201304#explicit-content) Please have a look at this. Also, make title a bit informative. [how to write a good title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title)

Comment: The region, set to US. I'm in Alaska. I've looked for other answers and noticed that some places prohibit it. So I checked the region and it is set to the United States. Okay, so what I noticed now was that the songs marked explicit, won't play right away, I left them alone and like after a couple of minutes they'll start to play. Not all of the explicit songs but a few of them.

Comment: I've done the screen time restrictions and I've got it to allow everything already.